# Is UITextView enough for a simple writing app?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitextview, ios

I'm trying to make a simple writing program, like Notes app for iPad, with a custom keyboard.
From OmniGroup's text editor open sources, I learned that `UITextInput` is mainly required to develop great text editor capable of having several fonts and size in one editor.
But it seemed tough to implement a lot of methods in `UITextInput` Protocol in order to build a text editor from scratch.

Do you think `UITextView` is enough to make a simple writing program?

Do most writing apps in AppStore use their own framework using `UITextInput`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITextView is the ideal view to display and edit multiple lines of text. You can format the text using font, size and color.  The only formatting restriction is that you can have only one text format for the whole view.  The Notes app written by Apple is a typically use of UITextView.

Check [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html) for more...

Cheers

Comment: Thank you! I found that I can make a simple note using UITextView's methods and properties such as selectedRange.